# WordPress ACF - Show Fields Based On A User Choice

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm wondering if it is possible to do the following:

I have an area of a site that could have either:

- A video
- An image
- Some written content

What I would normally do is create three different types of fields and then in the code check to see which one has been filled in and display that content.

What would be more useful is if in WP admin, the user could select the type of content they would like to add and this selection would then show the relevant field to populate.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, here's how you would set this up:

1. Make a radio button group (or checkbox if you wish to allow multiple selections.
   1a. Set one to Video, one to Image, and one to Text
2. Create your fields for the video selection, image selection, and text selection
3. At the bottom of each field's settings, there is a setting for conditional fields. Set Conditional Logic to yes. Then, for each field, set the desired value from the radio button group.

Suppose these were your fields:
Video - Text field looking for a youtube embed code
Image - Image field
Text - WYSIWYG editor

When creating/editing your page/post, you select Video from the radio button group.
That selection makes the text field for the youtube embed code appear.
You then paste the code into there and save you page/post.

Now, in your page/post template, you will want to use get_field() on your radio button group, and then build out some branching logic (if/else statement or a switch case), to build out your front end html/php template for each desired content type.